# Make an Android button change background on click through XML

Tags: android, onclick, android-button

Is there a way to specify an alternative background image/color for a Button in the XML file that is going to be applied `onClick`, or do I have to do a `Button.setBackground()` in the `onClickListener`?

Comment: For more details and implementation help refer to [the android docs](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html).

Answer (score 106, accepted):

To change the image by using code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   if(v.id == R.id.button_id) {
     ButtonName.setImageResource(R.drawable.ImageName);
   }
}
```

Or, using an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/login_selected" /> <!-- pressed -->
  <item android:state_focused="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/login_mouse_over" /> <!-- focused -->
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/login" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

In `OnClick`, just add this code:

```
ButtonName.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ImageName));
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for (the item state thing...)

Comment: @David,thanks for this post.i have couple of image buttons require this feature(change image on pressed)  what are changes needed in Selector & onClick for all? can you guide me?

Comment: where exactly do you point to that xml file in the second approach?

Comment: @Paul in the second approach put the xml file in the drawable folder and in the ImageView you want to use just set android:src="@drawable/xmlfile"

Comment: @Amyth Just change it to setImageDrawable

Answer (score 7):

In the latest version of the SDK, you would use the `setBackgroundResource` method.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   if(v == ButtonName) {
     ButtonName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ImageResource);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public void methodOnClick(View view){

Button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nameImage);

}
```

i recommend use button inside LinearLayout for adjust to size of Linear.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public void onclick(View v){
            ImageView activity= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
        button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.buttonpressed);}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this to change the background for my button

```
            button.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.primary_button));
```

"button" is the variable holding my Button, and the image am setting in the background is primary_button