# How to make Button highlight?

Tags: android

I set a image as Button backgroud,but Button has no highlight when click it.
Is there any way to solve it.

Comment: Refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125774/android-button-set-onclick-background-image-change-with-xml/4125877#4125877)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get you to the correct resource here is the documentation of the [StateList Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList). You just create and define it in your `res/drawable` subdirectory and set it as your buttons background.

Comment: Excellent answer!  What are you doing here in the past? ;-)

Answer (score 21):

If this is an ImageButton and you don't want to use several drawable for each pressed/unpressed state you could use the color filter attibute of images. This solution is similar to the one used by Omar.

Create an OnTouchListener modifying the color filter on touch.

```
public class ButtonHighlighterOnTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

  final ImageButton imageButton;

  public ButtonHighlighterOnTouchListener(final ImageButton imageButton) {
    super();
    this.imageButton = imageButton;
  }

  public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      //grey color filter, you can change the color as you like
      imageButton.setColorFilter(Color.argb(155, 185, 185, 185));
    } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
      imageButton.setColorFilter(Color.argb(0, 185, 185, 185)); 
    }
    return false;
  }

}
```

Assign this listener to your button:

```
  myButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
  myButton.setOnTouchListener(new ButtonHighlighterOnTouchListener(myButton));
```

**Update**

Improved class to apply highlighter to ImageView, ImageButton or TextView via its compound Drawable.

```
public class ButtonHighlighterOnTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

  private static final int TRANSPARENT_GREY = Color.argb(0, 185, 185, 185);
  private static final int FILTERED_GREY = Color.argb(155, 185, 185, 185);

  ImageView imageView;
  TextView textView;

  public ButtonHighlighterOnTouchListener(final ImageView imageView) {
    super();
    this.imageView = imageView;
  }

  public ButtonHighlighterOnTouchListener(final TextView textView) {
    super();
    this.textView = textView;
  }

  public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (imageView != null) {
      if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        imageView.setColorFilter(FILTERED_GREY);
      } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        imageView.setColorFilter(TRANSPARENT_GREY); // or null
      }
    } else {
      for (final Drawable compoundDrawable : textView.getCompoundDrawables()) {
        if (compoundDrawable != null) {
          if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // we use PorterDuff.Mode. SRC_ATOP as our filter color is already transparent
            // we should have use PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN with a non transparent color
            compoundDrawable.setColorFilter(FILTERED_GREY, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
          } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            compoundDrawable.setColorFilter(TRANSPARENT_GREY, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); // or null
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: Just one correction: You HAVE TO return true on the onTouch() to tell SO that you did some action in the touch action.

Comment: this is what i was looking for.. imageView.setColorFilter() works perfect

Answer (score 13):

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)

And also [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/tree/browse_frm/thread/1906f24707594f67/17322a04f7af1a5b)
for Romain Guy's answer:

> In res/drawable, create a file called for instance mybutton_background.xml 
>       and put something like this inside:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_background_focus" /> 

    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_background_pressed" /> 

    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_background_pressed" /> 

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_background_normal" /> 

</selector>
```

Then set this drawable as the background of your button with 
    `android:background="@drawable/mybutton_background"`

Comment: You can use a Proxy server to get there. Anyway, updated my answer with the solution (the one written by Romain Guy)

Answer (score 4):

if you are using

```
<Button 
  ------------------
android:background="@drawable/youimage"
>
```

Then as it is better to declare new a new xml. with the image you can specify image for each [event state](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList). as Octavian says
and you can you can set this xml as you background

if your xml is 'res/drawable/abc.xml' then set background as

```
android:background="@drawable/abc"
```

You can also use ImageButton

```
<ImageButton
----------------------
android:src="@drawable/youimage" 
 />
```

The benefit for ImageButton is that, no need of different image for highlight.

Answer (score 3):

Try this to get a poor man's highlight effect without the need of making multiple copies of your images. Set the alpha value 0.8 to a desired value:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class EAImageButton extends ImageButton {

    public EAImageButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }
    public EAImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context,attrs);
    }
    public EAImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
        super(context,attrs,defStyle);
    }
    public void setImageResource (int resId){
        super.setImageResource(resId);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e){
        if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            this.setAlpha((int)( 0.8 * 255));
        }else if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            this.setAlpha((int)( 1.0 * 255));
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(e);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I made it by override Button class

```
public class MButton extends Button {
public MButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public MButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

public MButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

//define style
public void setPressedBg(Integer[] mImageIds) {
    StateListDrawable bg = new StateListDrawable();
    Drawable normal = this.getResources().getDrawable(mImageIds[0]);
    Drawable selected = this.getResources().getDrawable(mImageIds[1]);
    Drawable pressed = this.getResources().getDrawable(mImageIds[2]);

    bg.addState(View.PRESSED_ENABLED_STATE_SET, pressed);
    bg.addState(View.ENABLED_FOCUSED_STATE_SET, selected);
    bg.addState(View.ENABLED_STATE_SET, normal);
    bg.addState(View.FOCUSED_STATE_SET, selected);
    bg.addState(View.EMPTY_STATE_SET, normal);
    this.setBackgroundDrawable(bg);
}

//define style
public void setPressedBg(Integer p1,Integer p2,Integer p3) {
    StateListDrawable bg = new StateListDrawable();
    Drawable normal = this.getResources().getDrawable(p1);
    Drawable selected = this.getResources().getDrawable(p2);
    Drawable pressed = this.getResources().getDrawable(p3);

    bg.addState(View.PRESSED_ENABLED_STATE_SET, pressed);
    bg.addState(View.ENABLED_FOCUSED_STATE_SET, selected);
    bg.addState(View.ENABLED_STATE_SET, normal);
    bg.addState(View.FOCUSED_STATE_SET, selected);
    bg.addState(View.EMPTY_STATE_SET, normal);
    this.setBackgroundDrawable(bg);
}
```

}

in my main()

```
toneButton.setPressedBg(R.drawable.button_tone_protrait_pipa,
            R.drawable.button_tone_protrait_pipa1,
            R.drawable.button_tone_protrait_pipa1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  **View.setFocusableInTouchMode** or **android:focusableInTouchMode**. In this case use this piece for your Button, either in XML or in the code itself. For details *refer :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html*

Comment: I'm China,there is GFW here,so I can't get http://developer.android.com/ 
thanks anyway