# Android highlight an imagebutton when clicked

Tags: android, imagebutton

I am using an `ImageButton`. But I don get the highlight when clicked. I googled and many suggested to use selector where another image is displayed. Is there any way around this. by using only one image and highlighting it or giving it a glow effect. so that the user knows that button has been clicked.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to create the image button?

Answer (score 36):

This is actually not very difficult to do. You don't even need to create 2 seperate .png files or anything like that. For instance, if you want to have a button which has a gradient, and then change it when the button is pressed:

Step 1:
Create default button gradient (drawable/default_button.xml):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <gradient android:endColor="#8ba0bb" android:startColor="#43708f" android:angle="90" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#33364252" />
</shape>
```

Step 2: Create default button pressed gradient (drawable/default_button_pressed.xml):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <gradient android:endColor="#43708f" android:startColor="#8ba0bb" android:angle="90" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#33364252" />
</shape>
```

Step 3: Create selector (drawable/default_button_selector.xml):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/default_button_pressed" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_button" /> 
</selector>
```

Step 4 *(optional)*: Create style for the button (values/style.xml):

```
<resources>
    <style name="DefaultButton">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>   
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/default_button_selector</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Step 5: use the button (layout/main.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <button style="@style/DefaultButton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see, it's not particularly difficult to do.

Comment: lol @Zack `As you can see, it's not particularly difficult to do.`

Comment: This is nice since you can easily add a number of buttons using this same style.

Comment: what if we need buttons with different background images?

Answer (score 21):

**Without having to create multiple images (pressed, normal etc) and even don't have to create selector.** Use setOnTouchListener rather than setOnClickListener. The below code will give you the grey overlay on the clicked item.

```
 ((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.myImageBtn)).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

      @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
              ImageButton view = (ImageButton ) v;
              view.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x77000000, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
              v.invalidate();
              break;
          }
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

              // Your action here on button click

          case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
              ImageButton view = (ImageButton) v;
              view.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
              view.invalidate();
              break;
          }
          }
          return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This worked for me. Make sure to clear the color filter on ACTION_UP also.

Comment: My ADT didn't know what 'PorterDuff' was, so suffix with 'android.graphics' (android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP) for hinted code completion

Comment: @AdamJohns, in the case of ACTION_UP there is no `break;` so it will clear it :)

Comment: This generates a a11y warning

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use **`android:foreground`** for your `View` to achieve clickable effect:

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

For use with dark theme add also *theme* to your **`layout`** (to make clickable effect clear):

```
android:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark"
```

Comment: Good for API Level > 23

Answer (score 3):

In order not to have to set several drawable for each button I set the color filter attribute of the image button in an on touch listener.

See code here in another post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14278790/891479

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do this!!
First you declare **buttonStyle.xml** in drawable folder.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
      android:state_focused="true"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" />

  <item
      android:state_focused="false"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" />

  <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" />
</selector>
```

Then you create **button_pressed.xml** in drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
  <solid android:color="@color/semiTransparentGnfrBlueColor" />
  <stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
```

After that, you create **button_normal.xml** in drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="@color/gnfrBlueColor"/>
  <stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
```

You can use default colors but if you want to do it like me, you need to have a file named **colors.xml** in values folder and this values inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<item name="gnfrBlueColor" type="color">#2A3748</item>
  <item name="semiTransparentGnfrBlueColor" type="color">#602A3748</item>
<integer-array name="androidcolors">
<item>@color/gnfrBlueColor</item>
    <item>@color/semiTransparentGnfrBlueColor</item>
  </integer-array>
</resources>
```

Finally you set this to your button or whatever:

```
savedAccountLoginButton.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.buttonStyle);
```

**NOTICE THAT** I set a **stroke with color transparent** because when you set backgroundresource your button becomes bigger and with this trick it remains original.

This is the only way I could archieve this programmatically.

If you want to do this by XML:

```
<Button
            android:text="ENTRAR"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonstyle"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:id="@+id/button1" />
```