# How to set button click effect in Android?

Tags: android

In Android, when I set a background image to a button, I can not see any effect on it when it's clicked.

I need to set some effect on the button, so the user can recognise that the button is clicked.

The button should be dark for a few seconds when it is clicked. How to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755871/how-to-set-image-button-backgroundimage-for-different-state/4755934#4755934

Comment: The following method allows you to use a single styleclass to skin all your buttons, regardless of their text: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327553/android-highlight-an-imagebutton-when-clicked/5327786#5327786

Comment: no I am not using Image Button , I am using Normal Button any easy way for this ?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

This can be achieved by creating a drawable xml file containing a list of states for the button. So for example if you create a new xml file called "button.xml" with the following code:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/YOURIMAGE" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/gradient" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/gradient" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/YOURIMAGE" />
</selector>
```

To keep the background image with a darkened appearance on press, create a second xml file and call it gradient.xml with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/YOURIMAGE"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <gradient android:angle="90" android:startColor="#880f0f10" android:centerColor="#880d0d0f" android:endColor="#885d5d5e"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

In the xml of your button set the background to be the button xml e.g.

```
android:background="@drawable/button"
```

Changed the above code to show an image (YOURIMAGE) in the button as opposed to a block colour.

Comment: Then where can I set Image for Button Background , to set Image is must

Comment: Edited to show how to use a background image with the state XML. Replace YOURIMAGE with the image resource in your drawable directory.

Comment: This only work if the src of the button is rectangular. If the src drawable has any shape diffenrent than that, the gradient will be applied to the background too, and this is sad.

Comment: Not really, could always use a different shape in the layer list

Comment: while i am using an image it works for me ..
but when i am using a Xml background. it is not working...

Comment: @VV hey did you find a solution for setting an xml background??

Comment: This is a more complex answer and does not provide the nice ripple effect. Francis' answer is better, just add android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"

Comment: @RenatoLochetti 
add 
            <corners android:radius="32dp" />

to 2nd layer to match the main shape.

Answer (score 95):

It is simpler when you have a lot of image buttons, and you don't want to write xml-s for every button.

Kotlin Version:

```
fun buttonEffect(button: View) {
    button.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                v.background.setColorFilter(-0x1f0b8adf, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
                v.invalidate()
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                v.background.clearColorFilter()
                v.invalidate()
            }
        }
        false
    }
}
```

Java Version:

```java
public static void buttonEffect(View button){
    button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    v.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xe0f47521,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                    v.invalidate();
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                    v.invalidate();
                    break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I use this in my code and the only problem I have noticed so far is that the button behaves weirdly when placed in a ScrollView.

Comment: It's really superb solution and this should be correct answer

Comment: How is this better? Designing should be kept outside of code, shouldn't it?

Comment: Its just a simple solution for this problem. When you have a lots of buttons and you dont want to create xmls for every single one it could be helpful.

Comment: Omg! Imagine having 5 buttons in a fragment... You will have whole bunch of this boilerplate code... How to refactor it then? Change colour filter for all the buttons in all the activities? Imho it's  your next developer will not be so happy..

Comment: It is a function, you can call it multiple times. The color code can be led out into xml

Comment: should also be one for MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL.  return false at the end is key so that any other listeners such as onClickListener will be called normally.

Comment: @Finnboy11 you need to handle ACTION_CANCEL as well, it will be called inside scrollview. The details could be found here https://github.com/thanhbinh84/clickable-image-view/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/thanhbinh84/clickableimageviewsample/EffectTouchListener.java

Comment: @Bahu - it might be because you're implementing this method inside an OnClick so it runs only after the OnClick method is run. You should put it in an outer scope like right after you get a reference to the button you want to enable this effect on.

Comment: How can I use both onTocuhListener and OnClickListener at the same time for single button/imageButton?

Comment: Best one out there

Answer (score 95):

You can simply **use foreground** for your **`View`** to achieve clickable effect:

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

For use with dark theme add also *theme* to your **`layout`** (to clickable effect be clear):

```
android:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark"
```

Comment: The easiest way to implement. FYI, Attribute android:foreground has no effect on API levels lower than 23.

Comment: Simplest solution.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, much simpler and it adds the nice ripple animation effect.

Comment: @dolgom For API level < 23 use it on "background" attribute.So:
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"

Comment: @Z3R0 `android:background="@drawable/bluebutton"` is already taken to set the image for the button. It can't be used twice. Hence older Android versions are out of luck. Only the accepted solution works, if the button has no transparency.

Comment: @Houman you are right, this will work only if you don't need to set up the background. Anyway actually I'm using Butterknife and @OnClick(R.id.id_bttn) to set up onCLick Listener, check it if you need in java (Butterknife binds your view, in kotlin you have native binding)

Comment: @Houman if the trasparency means the shape of the button, you can use ripple drawable (with the shape mask applied) as a `android:foreground`.

Comment: Simplest and Straight Forward.

Answer (score 94):

Create your `AlphaAnimation` Object that decides how much will be the fading effect of the button, then let it start in the `onClickListener` of your buttons

For example :

```
private AlphaAnimation buttonClick = new AlphaAnimation(1F, 0.8F);

// some code

public void onClick(View v) {
    v.startAnimation(buttonClick);
}
```

of course this is just a way, not the most preferred one, it's just easier

Comment: What I like about this solution, is that it doesn't require lots of selectors to be created, when you have many buttons each with their own custom images.

Comment: This does not fade the button on a touch down, it only fades it for a split second after the click is detected and the user's finger has already been lifted.

Comment: Nice and simple

Comment: @Doug Voss, you can set the duration of the animation to make it longer

Comment: what about onLongClick and 'circularReveal'?

Answer (score 27):

To make your item consistent with the system look and feel try referencing the system attribute `android:attr/selectableItemBackground` in your desired view's background or foreground tag:

```
<ImageView
    ...
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"      
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    ...
/>
```

Use both attributes to get desired effect before/after API level 23 respectively.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11513474/4683601

Comment: By far the simplest solution. Thanks!

Comment: But you are using an ImageView, not a Button with background set to an image.

Comment: @Houman It works on ImageButton and even LinearLayout etc

Answer (score 11):

Or using only one background image you can achive the click effect by using `setOnTouchListener`

Two ways

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.testBth)).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

      @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          switch (event.getAction()) {
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                  Button view = (Button) v;
                  view.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x77000000, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                  v.invalidate();
                  break;
              }
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                  // Your action here on button click
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                  Button view = (Button) v;
                  view.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                  view.invalidate();
                  break;
              }
          }
          return true;
        }
});
```

[image]

And if you don't want to use `setOnTouchLister`, the another way of achieving this is

```
    myButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(.setColorFilter(0xF00, Mode.MULTIPLY);

    StateListDrawable listDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
    listDrawable.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed}, drawablePressed);
    listDrawable.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.defaultValue}, myButton);

    myButton.setBackgroundDrawable(listDrawable);
```

Comment: there are errors in code in the 2nd way. What is the getCurrent() function? Also myButton is not a Drawable so it can not be added as state.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. I have corrected it, and myButton is an instance of Button class which supplies the method setBackgroundDrawable and it takes the Drawable instances, hence this will work.

Comment: Check out my answer which is based on your 2nd approach. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39430738/5229515

Comment: This should probably have "return false" at the end so it doesn't consume the event and any additional onClickListeners can be called.

Answer (score 11):

For all the views

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

But for cardview which has elevation use

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

For Circular click effect as in toolbar

```
android:background="?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground"
```

Also you need to set

```
 android:clickable="true"
 android:focusable="true"
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. `android:background="@drawable/bluebutton"` is used to set the background of the Button to an image. It is already taken. This can't work.

Comment: @Houman You can use ripple for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40008782/8663316

Answer (score 4):

This is the best solution I came up with taking hints from @Vinayak's answer. All the other solutions have different drawbacks.

First of all create a function like this.

```
void addClickEffect(View view)
{
    Drawable drawableNormal = view.getBackground();

    Drawable drawablePressed = view.getBackground().getConstantState().newDrawable();
    drawablePressed.mutate();
    drawablePressed.setColorFilter(Color.argb(50, 0, 0, 0), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

    StateListDrawable listDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
    listDrawable.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed}, drawablePressed);
    listDrawable.addState(new int[] {}, drawableNormal);
    view.setBackground(listDrawable);
}
```

**Explanation:**

getConstantState().newDrawable() is used to clone the existing Drawable otherwise the same drawable will be used. Read more from here:
[Android: Cloning a drawable in order to make a StateListDrawable with filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979440/android-cloning-a-drawable-in-order-to-make-a-statelistdrawable-with-filters)

mutate() is used to make the Drawable clone not share its state with other instances of Drawable. Read more about it here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#mutate()

**Usage:**

You can pass any type of View (Button, ImageButton, View etc) as the parameter to the function and they will get the click effect applied to them.

```
addClickEffect(myButton);
addClickEffect(myImageButton);
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, where I needed to have a transparent background but still get animation. Setting this solved it for me:

```
android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
```

Also this if you want to have circular effect:

```
android:background="?android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

Answer (score 3):

just wanna add another easy way to do this: If your ImageButton remains its background and you don't set it to null, it will work like a normal button and will show the click animation while clicking exactly like other buttons.The way to hide the background while it is still there:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
    android:paddingRight="1dp"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:src="@drawable/squareicon" />
```

The paddings won't let the background be visible and make the button act like other buttons.

Comment: this will keep the squared button border around the image if it is circular

Answer (score 3):

```
Step: set a button in XML with onClick Action:

 <Button
android:id="@+id/btnEditUserInfo"
style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="@dimen/txt_height"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/round_btn"
android:contentDescription="@string/image_view"
android:onClick="edit_user_info"
android:text="Edit"
android:textColor="#000"
android:textSize="@dimen/login_textSize" />

Step: on button clicked show animation point
//pgrm mark ---- ---- ----- ---- ---- ----- ---- ---- -----  ---- ---- -----

    public void edit_user_info(View view) {

        // show click effect on button pressed
        final AlphaAnimation buttonClick = new AlphaAnimation(1F, 0.8F);
        view.startAnimation(buttonClick);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  EditUserInfo.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }// end edit_user_info
```

Answer (score 3):

**Simple and easy way to set View click effect.**

> Method

```
public AlphaAnimation clickAnimation() {
    return new AlphaAnimation(1F, 0.4F); // Change "0.4F" as per your recruitment.
}
```

> Set in View

```
yourView.startAnimation(clickAnimation());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use RippleDrawable for Material Design state pressed/clicked effect.

In order to achieve this, create ripple item as an .xml under /drawable folder and use it in android:background for any views.

- Effect for icon pressed/clicked, use circular ripple effect, for example:

  `<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"
  />`
- Effect for view clicked with rectangle boundary, we can add ripple over the existing drawable like bellow:

  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:color="#000000">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_background_drawable"/>
  </ripple>`

Answer (score 2):

Create bounce.xml file fo animation

**LOCATION:**

> res->anim->bounce.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <scale
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromXScale="0.9"
        android:fromYScale="0.9"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />

</set>
```

Add this line in **onClick** to initialize

```
  final Animation myAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.bounce);
         button.startAnimation(myAnim);
```

You get the shrink effect in a button click.

Answer (score 0):

Making a minor addition to Andràs answer:

You can use `postDelayed` to make the color filter last for a small period of time to make it more noticeable:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    v.getBackground().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                    v.invalidate();
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                            v.invalidate();
                        }
                    }, 100L);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

You can change the value of the delay 100L to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using xml background instead of IMG, just remove this :

```
<item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/YOURIMAGE"/>
</item>
```

from the 1st answer that @Ljdawson gave us.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something to set button click effect in android-
1.I created a animation resource file to use as button click effect.
2.Created a animation listener.
3.On animation end I can set the task or activity which I want to start on button click.
4.Then set animation on button.

```
<scale
    android:duration="90"
    android:fromYScale="0.9"
    android:fromXScale="0.9"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:pivotX="50%"/>


Animation animationButton = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MyActivity.this,R.anim.bounce_button);

 animationButton.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                button.startAnimation(animationButton);


            }
        });

'''
I hope this will help.
```