# Common method or xml for Onclick changing of button color

Tags: android, button

I have around twenty custom buttons in my app, with a **different image** for each button.
I know that to create a *click* effect I have to create an XML resource like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7176006/501859), I have to created 20 different XML resources for my buttons.

Is there a better way to get the same result without creating separate XML resources for each button?

**Update:**
Can we make the button translucent when it is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution [Here](http://shikii.net/blog/android-button-background-image-pressedhighlighted-and-disabled-states-without-using-multiple-images/).

```
    public class SAutoBgButton extends Button {

  public SAutoBgButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public SAutoBgButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public SAutoBgButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  @Override
  public void setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable d) {
    // Replace the original background drawable (e.g. image) with a LayerDrawable that
    // contains the original drawable.
    SAutoBgButtonBackgroundDrawable layer = new SAutoBgButtonBackgroundDrawable(d);
    super.setBackgroundDrawable(layer);
  }

  /**
   * The stateful LayerDrawable used by this button.
   */
  protected class SAutoBgButtonBackgroundDrawable extends LayerDrawable {

    // The color filter to apply when the button is pressed
    protected ColorFilter _pressedFilter = new LightingColorFilter(Color.LTGRAY, 1);
    // Alpha value when the button is disabled
    protected int _disabledAlpha = 100;

    public SAutoBgButtonBackgroundDrawable(Drawable d) {
      super(new Drawable[] { d });
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onStateChange(int[] states) {
      boolean enabled = false;
      boolean pressed = false;

      for (int state : states) {
        if (state == android.R.attr.state_enabled)
          enabled = true;
        else if (state == android.R.attr.state_pressed)
          pressed = true;
      }

      mutate();
      if (enabled && pressed) {
        setColorFilter(_pressedFilter);
      } else if (!enabled) {
        setColorFilter(null);
        setAlpha(_disabledAlpha);
      } else {
        setColorFilter(null);
      }

      invalidateSelf();

      return super.onStateChange(states);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStateful() {
      return true;
    }
  }

}
```

Use this in xml:

```
<net.shikii.widgets.SAutoBgButton
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/button_blue_bg"
  android:text="Button with background image" />
```