# How to Style Button

Tags: android, xml, button

I am looking for a way to style my button like an example from an older question ([How to create standard Borderless buttons (like in the design guidline mentioned)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855791/how-to-create-standard-borderless-buttons-like-in-the-design-guidline-mentioned)) but some things were left out from the answer.

How can I add more than one value to an XML element, particularly `android:background ="";`?

I figured out how to make my buttons borderless, but I want them to have a really thin border, and a different background color. I have seen lots of tips online, but I can't find a way to put all my items together properly in code. Below is a copy pasted image with the top part representing the layout I want to achieve with the button name and a thumbnail image on the right hand side on the button with the button being a different color then the background of the app, and below that is a copy pasted image of the border style I'm trying to achieve, thin, touching borders between buttons. I have looked everywhere and tried many ideas but none seem to work properly, or some require me to have

`android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`

but this interacts with

`android:background="#22272D"`

[image]

I need to keep the text in the button because my app is going to translate the buttons text to the language of the users phone, so I can't make the whole button just an image. Below is my XML and the output, any recommendations to how I should change it would be of massive help!

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="6"
tools:context="com.aid.travelers.myapplication.Transportation">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/transportation_page"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/airport"
        android:id="@+id/AirportButton"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"/>

  <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/bicycle"
        android:id="@+id/BicycleButton"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I get your question, but I guess you want to custom the background of your button, and have a touch effect when you press it.

Have a look at this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7176006/5446285

You should create your own resource file background.xml (for example) that you create in your drawable folder.
The code should be like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/background_selected"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_unselected" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

You should now create 2 other files in your drawable folder : background_selected.xml, and background_unselected.xml.
To do so, I advise you something like this if you want a thin border :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#7c7c7c" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:bottom="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:left="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#a0a0a0" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Then you set the background of your button in your xml :

```
android:background="@drawable/background"
```

Comment: This was exactly perfect, thank you so much for your time, it worked great!