# Android button animation

Tags: android

I created a button in Android like this,
`Button btn = new Button(getContext());`

Initially, the button will be animated when I click on it. It becomes darker when I press on it, and it resumes to its original color when I release the button.

However, if I change the background color, such as `btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)`, the click animation will no longer there, and this really annoyed me.

What I want is simple, I just want to keep the click animation even I changed the button background color.

---

Updates:

Finally, I chose the library [Material](https://github.com/rey5137/material) for my project in case anyone want to know.

There are several Material UI libraries on Github that backward support SDK version <21, however, it seemed that each of them has its own problems and bugs. Most of them support constructions of UI components using XML quite well, but they do not support construction in Java very well. For example, it seemed that the library I am using cannot construct Material style `EditText` programmatically in Java.

I tried [RippleEffect](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect), [material-ripple](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple) and [Material](https://github.com/rey5137/material), and [Material](https://github.com/rey5137/material) worked better in my case.

Comment: Create a XML for it. This person explains it well: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7176006/4329778)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to make a `button` with `custom color` and `ripple effect`, then you should use `ripple drawable`.

1. Here is a `ripple drawable`, where button `background color` is `RED` and `ripple color` is `WHITE`. You can change color as per your needs.

**ripple_effect.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#88FFFFFF"> <!-- Ripple color :: WHITE -->

    <item>
        <color android:color="#FF0000" /> <!-- Normal bg color :: RED -->
    </item>

    <!-- Make sure the ripple doesn't exceed the bounds -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

2. Put `ripple_effect.xml` file in your `drawable` folder.
3. Use drawable `ripple_effect` as `button` background using `android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"`.

**Here is your `Button` XML:**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
    android:text="Button">

</Button>
```

**For Android api versions < 14**

To achieve `ripple effect`, you can try [balysv/material-ripple](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple) library.

1. In your `gradle`, add below line :

compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'

2. Wrap your `button` with `MaterialRippleLayout` in your layout file.
3. Add`ripple color` using app:mrl_rippleColor="#88FFFFFF" and don't forget to use `app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true"` to show `ripple effect` over `custom colored button`

**Here is your Button XML:**

```
<com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
    android:id="@+id/ripple"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:mrl_rippleColor="#88FFFFFF"
    app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:text="Button">

    </Button>
</com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: I forgot to mention that the minSdkVersion in my project is 16 (Android 4.1). Unfortunately, minSdkVersion 16 does not support `<Ripple>`. Is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: @Tim See my updated answer. For Android api versions < 14, you have to third party library. Its easy to use. Hope this will help you.

Comment: ripple only available for api 21+

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make simple animation with press stat for your button go and make new xml file in drawble and past this code , and you can chose the color you prefer . after go the your button and set background with the name of your xml you created

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#05FFCA"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
        </shape>

    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/amber"/>
        </shape>

    </item>
</selector>
```

`