# Android: add pressed effect on a button with image, text under it and custom border

Tags: android, xml, image, button, text

I'm working on a project where I have a Main Menu with buttons that have image and text under the image, they are already done:

[main menu buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ls40s.png)

To achieve that button layout with rounded corners, I put as background an xml called border_button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</shape>
```

And to keep background image and text with rounded corners, my button xml is like that:

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonMeusDados"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:background="@drawable/border_button"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/button_image_icon_meus_dados"
            android:text="@string/my_data"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

The problem now is that those buttons don't return any feedback to the user when pressed, they are static, no pressed animation

I found a lot of ways how to do that, but I'm not being able to mix them with what I already have, if I make the pressed effect animation, I lose all my retangle layout with rounded corners and etc

For the pressed effect I mainly followed @Ljdawson answer from this topic: [click effect on button in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175873/click-effect-on-button-in-android) but no success, as I explained above

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `border_button.xml` should be a selector. Like in the following example:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- the order of items is important. The first one that matches the state is rendered. -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" />
</selector>

        <!-- to make transition more visible you can slow it down. 
             Add this inside of selector tag, after the xmlns:android="..."
             android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
          -->
```

`button_pressed` and `button_normal` are xml files that draw pressed and normal states of the button, examples given bellow:

```
<!-- button_pressed.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
</shape>
```

and

```
<!-- button_normal.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Thanks a lot!