# Highlight a Button : Setcolor filer not working

Tags: android, button, highlight

I want to highlight a button when pressed and release without using any images,so i am using the below code from one the post on SO but its not working for me:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageButton myButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button);
    myButton.setOnTouchListener(new ButtonHighlighterOnTouchListener(myButton));
    }

    public class ButtonHighlighterOnTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    final ImageButton imageButton;

    public ButtonHighlighterOnTouchListener(final ImageButton imageButton) {
        super();
        this.imageButton = imageButton;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        //grey color filter, you can change the color as you like
        imageButton.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#5F2444"));
        System.out.println("called down");
        } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        imageButton.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#245F30"));
        System.out.println("called up");
        }
        return false;
    }

    }
```

What is the problem here?

Original post is here : [How to make Button highlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131656/how-to-make-button-highlight/14278790#14278790)

Comment: you need click/hover effect?

Comment: @Abhi hello buddy i need click effect buddy

Comment: Why dont you use selector for that simply?

Comment: i need to do it progrmatically

Comment: @Abhi i solved it myself i need one more help from you

Comment: Sure will try to help,You can come to chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28997/discussion-between-goofy-and-abhi)

Answer (score 2):

Ok i have solved it by myself hope it will help others too

```
public static void buttonEffect(View button) {
    button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            v.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xe0f47521, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            v.invalidate();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            v.invalidate();
            break;
        }
        }
        return false;
        }
    });
    }
```

You can change the color also , happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add this event in the switch, otherwise when the user clicks on the button and hold down until he go off the button, the button remains selected.

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
{
    v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
    v.invalidate();
    break;
}
```

I hope I was helpful