# Changing button background color on pressed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, background-image, background-color

I am new to android development. I have a button for which i have provided the selector as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/list"></item>
</selector>
```

By this i am able to achieve the background image change on button Pressed and on button Selected, but i want to change the background color also along with the image. is this possible ? If it is then please guide me how to achieve the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969925/how-to-highlight-a-button-when-is-pressed/17969979#17969979

Comment: If the image is covering the background of the button, what's the point of changing the background?

Answer (score 2):

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/onclick_home"> 

  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#94cd00" />

        <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:top="4dp" />

    </shape></item>
```

I have something like this to my imageview.It creates a green border outside my image view when it is pressed. see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
        //up event
        b.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        return true;
    }
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        //down event
        b.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is what the selector does actually, there's no point to do this in code.

Comment: This will only give the pressed state, not the selected state.

Comment: this also fails if I press down on the view, while still pressed down I slide my finger off the view, now I lift up. The color stays set. to the ACTION_DOWN color, it does not return to the ACTION_UP one