# manipulate android phone button callback

Tags: java, android, button, callback

I am a beginner in programming and I don't know much about it. I was asked to figure out how to "Manipulate an Android smartphone to do the following":

1) Create a button that would generate a callback (for example turn the screen from black to white)

2) Control the hardware of the device (Switch on the camera flash light, switch off the light)

I Would appreciate any help as I don't know what steps I should take to achieve this as I am an absolute beginner.

Answer (score 0):

1)[Change background after click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571366/changing-button-background-color-on-pressed)

2)[How to use camera](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html)

But first follow [Android training](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) to understand how Activities works