# How to reset other view style (button) or reset all button background in layout at once?

Tags: android, android-layout

I`m have 3 button in layout. I wish that when click one button, the styles of the other 2 buttons was set to "default". In my example: background color.
Pressing button1 must change her style and resets the styles of other buttons.

The simplest solution is to set the style of each button, on each method call, but this is the simplest solution, if the layer is only 2-5 buttons, but if there will be 10-20?

In drawable/button_bg.xml i have selector with 2 state: default and state_selected.
Is it possible to reset (or set) all styles of all buttons in the layer (layout) instantly and without reloading the app?

Or, if the button is not pressed, assign the default style? Or something like layout.AllButtons.setDefaultStyle(true) (sorry for that)
[When click on one button, need to change styles for other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o3Qx.jpg)

As you see now state_selected not reset after new click on other button.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969925/how-to-highlight-a-button-when-is-pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it manually by iterating over layout and setting needed params like

```
private void unselectButtons(ViewGroup root, View except) {
    int childCount = root.getChildCount()
   for (int i=0; i < childCount; ++i) {
      View child = root.getChildAt(i);
      if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
        unselectButtons((ViewGroup)child,except);
      } else if (child instanceof Button && child != except) {
        child.setSelected(false);
      }

   }


}
```

Comment: It is working. Thanks. But only if declare count separately in method unselectButtons `Integer count = root.getChildCount();
        for (int i=0; i < count; ++i)`