# how to change the (image color) of buttons?

Tags: android

I have 4 bottons and I set a image as a background on each button. 
What I want to do is that the button should turn into gray when not selected
and turn into its original image color when selected. 
how can I do this??

```
     <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_settingTab"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="@drawable/setting_icon"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Comment: Use a selector.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969925/how-to-highlight-a-button-when-is-pressed

Comment: search for android button slector

Answer (score 1):

Why not you use Toggle Button?

Create a xml name like_button.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/likeactivepressed" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/likeinitialpressed"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/likeon"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/likeinitial"/>
</selector>
```

Then define it in your button like this

```
 android:background="@drawable/like_button"
```