# How to add a color filter to a button on click?

Tags: android, filter, onclick, state

I have modified the following [How to make Button highlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131656/how-to-make-button-highlight/14278790#14278790) to this application.

But it seems I cant set the color filter to the button the way that I have done it.The error I'm getting is `The method setColorFilter(PorterDuffColorFilter) is undefined for the type Button` ,which I understand means that I can't use it with a button object but is there a way around this? Does anyone know how I could implement this in a similar way?

I declared the filter here:

```
//button filter
    PorterDuffColorFilter greenFilter =  new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

And tried to implement it on the button click here:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {

            String getoffsetlength = offsetLength.getText().toString(); 
            String getoffsetdepth = offsetDepth.getText().toString(); 
            String getductdepth = ductDepth.getText().toString(); 

            double tri1,tri2;
            double marking1,marking2,marking3;

            double off1 = Double.parseDouble(getoffsetlength);
            double off2 = Double.parseDouble(getoffsetdepth);
            double off3 = Double.parseDouble(getductdepth);


            //vibrate button onClick
            myVib.vibrate(20);

                //change button filter on click
            calculate.setColorFilter(greenFilter);




        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Must enter a numeric value!");


        }
//      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an ImageButton and call .setColorFilter on the ImageView that is set to the source of the ImageButton.