# Android studio Java Project

Tags: java, android

How do I randomly highlight a button in Android studio. For example, there are 4 buttons/views and I want one of them randomly highlighted, then if users correctly select the highlighted one, the other buttons will be randomly highlighted and previous highlighted buttons will be remain visible but not highlighted

I have tried browsing online to find related methods, but unsuccessful

Comment: Do you know how to highlight a *specific* button in Android? Do you know how to pick a random element from an array/collection? If so, combine those two and you're done. If not, show/tell us which of those you can do and where the issue is.

Comment: I dont know how to highlight a specific button

Comment: So you need this one: [How to make Button highlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131656/how-to-make-button-highlight)

Comment: but that one didnt mention how to make button highlight without touching them

Comment: Yes, and that's where you combine what you learned with other things. So now you know how to highlight a button. Next figure out how to pick a random button to highlight... and so on and so on. ...