# What is the best way to design screen 9X9 grid of Clickable cells to on/off like a game screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

In my Android application,

I have a screen where there is a grid of 9X9 cells(Button/Images).

I require to indicate the state of the cell Selected or Unselected using two different Images as Background(like: on and off).

Right now I am taking button and on click of the Button, I am changing the Background Image of the Button from On to Off and vice-versa.

My questions are,

1.**from the point of "Clean Code", is this a right way to handle it?**

2.**Is there a better way to do the task?**

(Note : I want to keep the option to click a button even when it's already toggled on, for future features)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can take Button, As generally programmers do but I suggest to take `ToggleButton` instead.

*Benefit of using ToggleButton over a Button is that you will not require to maintain the state of button programmatically using any flags to remember the user has selected the button once or not* ,below is a demo code for the same:

**XML in Layout folder**

```
 <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/tbApp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_toggle_button"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn="" />
```

**selector_toggle_button.xml in Drawable folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_on" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_off" />
</selector>
```

and **Java code to get Click on it**,

```
tbApp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                                         //if isChecked==true then selected 
                                         //else deselected
                               }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125774/android-button-set-onclick-background-image-change-with-xml)

or

[android docs](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html)

Check if this is what you are looking for