# Android - Highlighting of buttons

Tags: android, button, border, drawable

I have a few buttons which I want to highlight only at the borders.

That is, I want the borders of the buttons to glow with a specific color on some action taken. How do I change the border programatically?

Is it possible with drawables? How?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125774/make-an-android-button-change-background-on-click-through-xml

I hope this helps.

Comment: On the press state of selector xml use stroke attribute for change the border width and color.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two drawables one for selected state and one for normal state, please go
 through following link:

[StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

And also here: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/tree/browse_frm/thread/1906f24707594f67/17322a04f7af1a5b for Romain Guy's answer:

In res/drawable, create a file called for instance mybutton_background.xml 
and put something like this inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" 
android:drawable="@drawable/button_background_focus" /> 
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" 
android:drawable="@drawable/button_background_pressed" /> 
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" 
android:drawable="@drawable/button_background_pressed" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_background_normal" /> 
</selector>
```

Then set this drawable as the background of your button with

```
android:background="@drawable/mybutton_background"
```