# Button look depending on its state

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem. I do not know how to change the look of the button depending on its state.

The standard look in xml doesn't work and the default does not work either.

```
{
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

    button1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction()) 
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        mp[0] = loadSample(1);
                        mp[0].start(); 
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mp[0].stop(); 
                        //mp.reset();
                        mp[0].release(); 
                        break;  
                }
        return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is mp? Where are you trying to change the look?

Comment: MediaPlayer I would think.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make an Android button change background on click through XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125774/make-an-android-button-change-background-on-click-through-xml)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for an `ImageButton` with a selector for the image. This allows you to define `pressed`, `focused`, and `normal` states for a given button.

Example is pulled straight from the `ImageButton` API page. Once implemented as below, Android will automatically select the image that fits with the current state of the button based on the selector you define.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

As XML in the `drawable` folder:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
         <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
         <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
         <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
    </selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you do something like this in the XML?

```
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item android:drawable="@drawable/myButtonYellow" 
        android:state_pressed="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/myButtonNotYellow" />
</selector>
```

The android:state_pressed="true" line will set it up so that it will vary according to its pressed state. A full list of states can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html)

myButton is defined as:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners android:radius="4dp" />

    <solid android:color="@color/yellow" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="7dp"
        android:left="12dp"
        android:right="12dp"
        android:top="7dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/white" />

</shape>
```