# Rectangle shape Button with Circular icon on top in Android

Tags: android, button, icons, android-custom-view, android-button

As I am new to Android, I have no clue to create a button like below in 1:

[image]

Button should posses:

1. Normal background purple and when clicked should turns to red. (achieved)
2. Circular Icon on top-left of button, half icon in button and half portion of icon outside the button.
3. Arrow image on Right inside button.(achieved)

Is there any way to achieve this icon on top-left of button. I have the icon images in both red and purple color for each button separately.

With below implementation, I am able to achieve result as in PART 2 of Above Image:

Activity XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_ETOPUP"
        style="@style/btnServiceTheme"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/service_etopup"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_QuickPay"
        style="@style/btnServiceTheme"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/service_QuickPay"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_EVouchers"
        style="@style/btnServiceTheme"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/service_EVouchers"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Style XML:

```
<style name="btnServiceTheme" parent="AppTheme">
<item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:drawableRight">@mipmap/arrow_right_white</item>
<item name="android:background">@drawable/button_service</item>
<item name="android:layout_marginLeft">20dp</item>
<item name="android:layout_marginRight">20dp</item>
<item name="android:paddingTop">20dp</item>
<item name="android:paddingBottom">20dp</item>
<item name="android:paddingRight">25dp</item>
<item name="android:drawablePadding">-25dp</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
<item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
```

Selector XML:

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/purple" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true" />
</selector>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use FrameLayout you can achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below XML as a separate layout component:

```xml
<FrameLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center">

   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="35sp"
       android:layout_height="35sp"
       android:elevation="3dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
       android:scaleType="fitCenter"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_logo_bmw" />
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/btn_get_data"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_margin="10dp"
       android:background="@drawable/rectangular_bg"
       android:text="Quick-Pay"
       android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Using include tag to use this in your respective XML layout. Your output will be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but how can I change this Icon image when the button is clicked?

Comment: Add a custom button background and set it to your button. Set an ID for the button and add an OnClickListener for the same.  Follow the instructions in this link to change the button background resource onClick. [Make an Android button change background on click through XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125774/make-an-android-button-change-background-on-click-through-xml)