# How to set the background of the material button when focus with keyboard android?

Tags: android

I have material button. By default when screen open it suppose not to have a background but if I use keyboard and select it it need to change the background and add stroke border around.
I have created selector and shape. But for some reason if I apply selector file the regular style not working.

Button code

```
  style="@style/LogoutButton"
  android:enabled="true"
  app:backgroundTint="@null"
  android:background="@drawable/focus_selector"
```

focus_selector code

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/focus_shape"/>
</selector>
```

style code

```
<item name="backgroundTint">@color/button_state_selector_black</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/button_state_text_color_selector_white</item>
```

Comment: Try this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125774/make-an-android-button-change-background-on-click-through-xml

Comment: @Deepa I don't need it on click. When you use keyboard you are not clicking on the element you are focusing it and make it in select but its not click

Answer (score 0):

Use `state_pressed="true"` instead of `state_focused="true"` for your requirement

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/focus_shape"/>
</selector>
```